# Display a QAbstractTableModel in a QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, qabstractitemmodel, qabstracttablemodel

Good evening StackOverflow. This is my first question, so I hope it will not be too dumb.

I have a model sublassing `QAbstractTableModel` that stores items inheriting `QObject`. I want to display the list of the items in a `QComboBox`, which is updated when the model changes.

The model implements the four needed functions `rowCount()`, `columnCount()`, `data()` and `headerData()`.

My question is : how is used a `QAbstractItemModel` in a `QComboBox` when using `QComboBox::setModel()` ? (in other words, does column count must be equal to 1, for instance ?).

And how do I choose the text diplayed for each item in the `QComboBox` when using a `QAbstractModel` ? 
I have found a `objectName()` method in `QObject` but I'm not really sure on the way it is used.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass your QAbstractTableModel providing columnCount() that return 1.

Then, when you will override

```
QVariant QAbstractItemModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole)
```

you must react to `role`. If it's DisplayRole you will return text that you get from your model's objects